# libfreetype6 errors are every where!

Tags: apt, libraries

when I run any type of apt-related command there is no way which I don't see an error related to libfreetype6, like this:

```
nima@cesar:~$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-gettext is already the newest version (1.0.12-0.1).
php-mbstring is already the newest version (1:7.2+60ubuntu1).
phpmyadmin is already the newest version (4:4.6.6-5).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfreetype6 : Breaks: libfreetype6:i386 (!= 2.8-0.2) but 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libfreetype6:i386 : Breaks: libfreetype6 (!= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8-0.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And when I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` :

```
nima@cesar:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libfreetype6
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libfreetype6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/335 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 246228 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfreetype6:amd64 (2.8.1-2ubuntu2) over (2.8-0.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libfreetype6/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libfreetype6:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6_2.8.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And I don't know what is the problem and how I can fix it!

Comment: Please add the error in the description than posting the image link

Comment: @kvmahesh Done!

Comment: Try the following: `sudo dpkg -r libfreetype6 && sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install libfreetype6` After this is done try to install your wanted targets (i.e. phpmyadmin etc.)

Comment: @Videonauth I got an error: `dpkg: error processing package libfreetype6:amd64 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfreetype6:amd64`

Comment: Then try: `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libfreetype6`